# I am trying to read an image from Gallery On app Starting Up that is pre set by the user Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am Saving the Path to an Image that is set by the user, when the app starts up from cold the image path is read from file and is(should be displayed) but it doesn't want to show. is there a simpler method to reading a set image from gallery?

This is my read File, within this Internal file I am saving a String Path to the Image

```
fun readDataLocally(context: Context, FileName: String): String {
var str = ""
try {
    val inputStream = context.openFileInput(FileName)
    if (inputStream != null) {
        val inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
        val partialStr = StringBuilder()
        var done = false
        while (!done) {
            val line = bufferedReader.readLine()
            done = (line == null)
            if (line != null) partialStr.append(line)
        }
        inputStream.close()
        str = partialStr.toString()
    }
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
    Log.e("Error: ", "file not found: " + e.toString())
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Log.e("Error: ", "cannot read file: " + e.toString())
}
Log.d("FileRead",str)
return str
```

}

This reads the Image path and sets the bit map, any time I call this method it causes the Exception E.

```
fun readImageFromPath(context: Context, path : String) : Bitmap? {
var bitmap : Bitmap? = null
val uri = Uri.parse(path)
Log.d("path",path)
if (uri != null) {
    try {
        val parcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
        val fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
        parcelFileDescriptor?.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Image Read is unavailable please reload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
Log.d("Rip", bitmap.toString())
return bitmap
```

}

Methods used too call Image to show on Activity Start Up

```
ImageView.setImageBitmap(readImageFromPath(this,readDataLocally(this, "HomeImage")))
```

and I tried

```
 val bitmap = readDataLocally(this, "HomeImage")

 ManagerScreen_Image.setImageBitmap(readImageFromPath(this, bitmap))
```

I have the Correct Manifest Permissions.

Comment: Instead of saving the path in a file, you should be saving it as a key-value pair using [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).
For the exception, please add a `Log.e(e)` statement in the `catch` block to log the exception and paste the output here.

Comment: `fun readDataLocally` Can you give an example of the path that it returns?

Comment: `readImageFromPath(context: Context, path ` Can you give an example of the value of path with which you call this function?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context,"Image Read is unavailable please reload",` That is your own message and tells nothing. Instead you should display e.getMessage() to the user. And to yourself!

Comment: The Path to the Image is being saved as followed "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A27"   The Problem is when I run on an Emulator the App Functions correctly Image is loaded On App Start but when I Run it on A Physical Device I get The Image Read is Unavailable.

Comment: BlackApps Thanks the {e.message} gave me the needed Explanation for why it wouldn't Read.  An Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is needed to open specific documents, I was just trying to read the data.